# Как правильно работать с жадной загрузкой при использовании виджета ListView?

Tags: yii2

Пытаюсь организовать работу `LIstView` со связями и жадной загрузкой вот так так организую жадную загрузку

```
$allGods=Gods::find()->with('prise','images','addfeilds')->all();
```

вот так предаю в представление

```
    <?= ListView::widget([
         'dataProvider'  => $productsDataProvider,
         'itemView'      => '_gods',
         'viewParams' => [
         'allGods'       => $allGods,]
 ]) ?>
```

пытаюсь так использовать в виде

```
var_dump($model->images)
```

получаю дополнительный `sql` запрос. 
Понимаю что делаю что то не так. Не подскажите как правильно ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Имхо, если вы передаете провайдер данных в ListView, то передавать  'allGods'       => $allGods ненужно.

Вот пример

```
// Действие в контроллере
public function actionGods() {
    $provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Gods::find()->with('prise','images','addfeilds')
    ]);
    $this->render('view', ['provider' => $provider]);
}

// Вызов ListView во view
<?= ListView::widget([
    'itemView'      => '_gods',
    'dataProvider'  => $provider        
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`with` на yii2 создает отдельный запрос с `where in ...`
Чтобы запрос был один с джоинами надо указать `joinWith()` вместо `with()`